# Реализация кнопок awt

Tags: java, gui, awt

Плохо понимаю принцип реализации кнопок. Буду признателен за разъяснения.
P.S. как реализовать увеличение/уменьшение на каждое нажатие,а не 1 раз?

```
public class GUI extends Frame {

    public GUI() throws HeadlessException {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Test window");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                //System.exit(0);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        String fontName = "Arial";
        int fontStyle = 10;
        int fontSize = 12;

        Font font = new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
        Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
        Panel textPlacePanel = new Panel();
        Panel buttonPlacePanel = new Panel();
        Button increaseButton = new Button("Increase");


        Button decreaseButton = new Button("Decrease");
        Label label = new Label("Font size");
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setFont(font);

        frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPlacePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(textPlacePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        buttonPlacePanel.add(label);
        buttonPlacePanel.add(increaseButton);
        buttonPlacePanel.add(decreaseButton);
        textPlacePanel.add(textArea);

        increaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = font.getSize();
                Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,++i);
                textArea.setFont(font);
            }
        });
        decreaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i = font.getSize();
                Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,--i);
                textArea.setFont(font);
            }
        });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: C параметрами фрейма- setVisible(true) не там стоял где надо.
А с кнопками все еще проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что размер шрифта вы берете у внешнего объекта `font`, который вы не изменяете, поэтому работает только 1 раз.

```
int i = font.getSize();
Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,++i);
textArea.setFont(font);
```

Получайте шрифт из TextArea и берите его размер. В обоих случаях:

```
int i = textArea.getFont().getSize();
Font font = new Font(fontName,fontStyle,++i);
textArea.setFont(font);
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!это то, что нужно